# Carousel team member by html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tln19.png)
I don't know how to make a carousel like this, can u help me?

I have try to do this and it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @levius, what have you tried already, can you show us your code?